# OAuth 2.0 Set AccessToken

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I am new with OAuth but because it looks very interesting, I wanted to take a look at it. I have read and viewed some tutorials and I understand the basics. I downloaded this BitBucket provider: https://github.com/stevenmaguire/oauth2-bitbucket which uses this client: https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client

The thing I don't understand is: how do I set the accessToken? When there is no ?code in the url it redirects and adds it to the url, then I get the accessToken and the refreshToken but how do I use that accessToken? I've tried some things, also $provider->setAccessToken() but that function doesn't exist.

Hope someone can help me. It's probably pretty easy but I don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access token you received will not need to be set explicitly with any method. There are methods to get the user's details where this access token should be passed as parameter. As written in the [documentation](https://github.com/stevenmaguire/oauth2-bitbucket) you provided:

```
// Try to get an access token (using the authorization code grant)
$token = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
    'code' => $_GET['code']
]);

// Optional: Now you have a token you can look up a users profile data
try {

    // We got an access token, let's now get the user's details
    $user = $provider->getResourceOwner($token);

    // Use these details to create a new profile
    printf('Hello %s!', $user->getId());

} catch (Exception $e) {

    // Failed to get user details
    exit('Oh dear...');
```

Here getResourceOwner method should be given the token and the user details related to the $token will be returned.